# Custom item in theme

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to create style that I will use in `android:textAppearance` of my TextView. But this style differs on different API levels, so I want to have:

- one common style (for all API levels),
- some styles that inherits after that common style in values-v16, values-v21 dirs,
- one directive (style / attr ?) I will put in TextView's `android:textAppearance` parameter (layout files are common for all API levels).

I tried multiple combinations from Google and Stack and finally ended with something like this (which is of course not working):

values/attrs.xml

```
<attr name="myTextAppearance" format="reference" />
```

values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="myTextAppearance">@style/CommonTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="CommonTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00f</item>
</style>
```

values-v16/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="myTextAppearance">@style/V16TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="V16TextAppearance" parent="CommonTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

layout/activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Lorem"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/myTextAppearance"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And currently I'm getting an error:

> Couldn't find theme resource ?attr/myTextAppearance for the current theme

I spent a lot of time trying to do this on my own, but I failed. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ?attr/[name] value is a reference to the owner's style parameter. If there's no paraneter with [name], the code falls back to the default parameter set which is defined in a theme.

Basically, the TextView class checks the inline style defined in layout xml, then the default theme and then the textViewStyle reference. None of them contains your myTextAppearance attribute.

You have to override the view and in constructor use obtainStyledAttributes. Pass your theme attribute as the default one. Then parse the value and use it as the new text appearance.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#obtainStyledAttributes(android.util.AttributeSet,int[],int,int)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int)

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would have to override every widget I use with my attributes - TextView, Button, etc.? Is there no way to accomplish something I need (overriden styles for different APIs) in more friendly way, using only XML?

Comment: I would say so, but the styling mechanism is a bit messy, so I'm not dead certain. Also, I spotted that you have declared the attribute without declare-styleable. Maybe that's the reason?